# How to ignore Content Caching Servers for Updates in macOS?

Tags: macos

At work, I'm in a Network with many Macs. Someone has enabled the caching server on his Mac and it seems to be out of memory. Thus, most system and security updates on my Mac will fail. I know I can find the IP address of the Serving Mac by using `AssetCacheLocatorUtil` in Terminal. But I don't know whom I ask to disable the Content Caching as I can't get the Name of the Mac (`smbutil status IP` fails).

Is there a way to tell my Mac not to use a Content Caching Server for loading updates? If not, can I block the IP address completely so that my Mac won't see the Caching Server in the network?

Comment: Why not refer this to IT? Either they want to know their caching is failing or that someone has switched on caching without authority.

Comment: I know I can use this way, but it can also happen in other environments. And my question is of general interest.